# React and Axios download a file from Node JS server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to download a file in React from a Node JS and Express server. In the server I have created an endpoint that shows a download popup when I navigate to in the browser.

```
router.get("/getfile", (req, res) => {
  res.download("public/FILE.pdf");
});
```

But how do I trigger this browser popup window to save the file in the users own filesystem using React and Axios?

```
  donwloadFile = () => {
    axios.get("localhost:3030/getfile").then(function (response) {});
  };
```

Comment: Can you just show the link to the file *as a link* on the page? Then that window opens automatically.

Comment: Is there a reason for using AJAX? You could simply navigate to the file: `<a href="http://localhost:3030/getfile">Download</a>`

Answer (score 1):

you have to install "js-file-download" library inreact using following command

```
npm install --save js-file-download
```

then change the code in react file as follows:

```
import download from 'js-file-download';
downloadFile = () => {
   axios.get("localhost:3030/getfile")
     .then(resp => {
            download(resp.data, fileName);
     });
}
```

the code at server side is as follows:

```
router.get("/getfile", (req, res) => {
  FileLocation ="public/FILE.pdf"
  file="File.pdf"
 res.download(fileLocation, file, (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            });
});
```

My reference for this answer is [in this link](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/bbtmi8/download_file_from_node_express_server_to_react/).

This works for me.I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a `content type header` before sending the file.

*index.js*

```
router.get('/caderno1', (req, res) => {
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.status(200).sendFile(__dirname + '/cadernos/CADERNO1.pdf');
});
```

When I implement this i used the method `sendFile`. I don't know if it works with `res.download`.

Here is my simplified file tree structure:

```
├── cadernos
|   ├── caderno1.pdf
|   └── caderno2.pdf
├── _server
|   └── index.js
├── app.js
└── package.json
```

Comment: It already works with res.download. When I enter the url in my browser I get a popup to download the file. I only need the same popup to come in React. But I don't know how.

Comment: have you tried to use content disposition header? res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename='/cadernos/CADERNO1.pdf');